# NavController.getBackStackEntry() dosent work as exptected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

Trying to find if destination contains in back stack using `NavController.getBackStackEntry(R.id.destination)` but im always getting `IllegalArgumentException`. Im 100% sure that destination that im trying to find is in back stack (i checked it in debug mode via `navController.backStack`). Documentation to `getBackStackEntry` function is `@param destinationId ID of a destination that exists on the back stack`.
I noticed that `R.id.destination` value is different from one that was in the graph, so i tryed to recive correct one from `graph[R.id.destination]` and `graph.findNode(R.id.destination)` but i got IAE and null.

What am i doing wrong and how to get correct destinationID to pass it to function?

Answer (score 0):

All these methods dosent work in debug evaluate expression (in which i was testing thoose).
If launched in regular app logic all is working fine